# Woher kommt das "die" in Ausdrücken wie "an die tausend Besucher"?

Tags: sentence-structure

In einer Frage in diesem Forum wurde die Behauptung aufgestellt, Formulierungen wie

> an die tausend Besucher

seien semantisch zu erklären als

> an (die Tausend) Besucher

wobei "die Tausend" das Zahl-Substantiv meine, das ja weiblich ist.

Diese Auffassung wurde angegriffen mit der Gegenthese, dass das *die* in diesem Ausdruck vielmehr zu *die Besucher* gehöre (und dass *tausend* hier einfach nur als Zahlwort zu lesen sei) also

> an die (tausend) Besucher

Ich war kurz geneigt, der zweiten These zu folgen, denn man kann ja auch sagen.

> Es kamen an die 753 Besucher

Das ist zwar stilistisch nicht gut, denn wenn man die genaue Zahl kennt, ist eine Annäherungsformel wie "an" unsinnig (noch deutlicher in: "Es kamen circa 753 Besucher" - ein typischer Stilfehler aus der Journalistenschule).  Gleichwohl ist der Satz *grammatisch* in Ordnung, denn auch *die Siebenhundertdreiundfünfzig* kann als ein weibliches Substantiv gelesen werden.

Gibt es nun, über diese beiden wohl gleich starken Vermutungen hinaus, Kenntnisse über die Herkunft der Formulierung und somit den Ur-Sinn des *die*?

Comment: Der Duden hat ja einen eigenen Eintrag für [an die](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/an_die) - das spricht m.E. eher für die zweite These.

Comment: Vermutlich verwandt: [So and die in this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54509/so-and-die-in-this-question)

Comment: Wäre "die" ein Artikel für "Tausend" würde man "Tausend" groß schreiben, oder?

Comment: Ich würde eher an eine Skala, zum Beispiel auf einem Maßstab denken: "Das Wasser stieg bis (nahe) an die 5 Meter (-Marke)." Davon dann abgeleitet auf andere Skalen und Größen, "Die Zahl der Besucher stieg bis an die tausend". Davon dann wieder abgeleitet, "Es kamen an die tausend Besucher".

Comment: @userunknown  Ich wäre (zumindest) vorsichtig mit dem Ableiten einer inneren Sprachlogik von Schreibkonventionen. Sonst könnte heute einer kommen und sagen *aufwändig* komme von *Wand*. (Ja, ich weiß, ein böses Beispiel.)

Comment: Kein böses, aber m.E. auch kein gutes Beispiel. Groß-/Kleinschreibregeln sind nicht trivial und stecken voller Ausnahmen - Etymologie dagegen hat ihre eigenen Fallstricke, wie etwa wissen zu müssen, was vorher war, "der Aufwand" oder das "ich wende auf". Ich zweifle noch, ob das "die" in "an die" überhaupt ein Artikel ist.

Comment: Die angesprochene Frage ist diese: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/55056/genders-in-the-babylon-dictionary

Comment: Siehe auch: https://www.dwds.de/wb/an (III mit Akk., vor Zahlen)

Comment: Ich würde schon sagen, Tausend ist hier ein nominativartriges Zahlwort/Pronomen, und trägt den Artikel "die."

Comment: *Es kamen circa 753 Besucher" - ein typischer Stilfehler aus der Journalistenschule* - Ooch, ich als Physiker habe auch kein Problem mit der Angabe *circa 753 Besucher*, wenn beispielsweise der Messfehler (Zählfehler) 4 beträgt, es also 753 +/-4 Besucher waren (mindestens 749 und höchstens 757).

Answer (score 4):

Wenn ich darüber nachdenke, möchte ich eine dritte These aufstellen und das so gruppieren.

> (an die) tausend Besucher

Ich habe keine Regel dazu parat, aber "an" oder "die" alleine ergeben keinen sinnvollen Ausdruck. Ich halte das Konstrukt "an die" für einen alternativen Ausdruck für "knapp".

Etwas weiter gefasst wäre "etwa", wobei dann auch mehr als tausend Besucher gemeint sein könnten. Die Formulierung "an die" drückt für mich gefühlsmäßig aus dass die Zahl nicht ganz, oder höchstens ganz knapp erreicht wurde.

Comment: Sehe ich auch so. Bei "*etwa tausend*" würde ich den Unsicherheitsspielraum nach oben und unten ungefähr gleich einschätzen, bei "*an die tausend*" kann der tatsächliche Wert deutlich tiefer, aber nur minimal höher liegen (und der Vollständigkeit halber: "*bis zu tausend*" lässt praktisch kein Überschreiten zu).

Comment: Interessante These...

Comment: Ich finde, dass Duden mit seinem Eintrag zu "an die" diese These stützt: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/an_die

Answer (score 2):

Es liegt nahe, die Konstruktion zurückzuführen auf *reichen* mit *an* und Akkusativ.

> Die Zahl der Besucher **reicht an die tausend**.

*An die* muß irgendwann als *etwa* reanalysiert worden sein und bleibt in allen Kasus unverändert. In den beiden folgenden Beispielen läßt es sich daher durch *etwa* ersetzen.

> Es wird mit **an die** tausend Besuchern gerechnet.

Da *an die* als *etwa* gelesen wird, kann ein Artikel vorangehen.

> Der Leiter der Stiftung hieß **die** an die hundert erschienenen Gäste willkommen.

Wenn man *an die* als Adverb mit der Bedeutung *etwa, fast* versteht, hat das den Vorteil, daß folgende Sätze parallel analysiert werden können als Verbindung eines Zahlwortes mit einem modifizierenden Adverb.

> mit **an die** tausend Zuschauern
>   mit **fast** tausend Zuschauern
>   mit **genau** tausend Zuschauern
>   mit **über** tausend Zuschauern

Wenn man dagegen *an die tausend* als Einheit auffaßt, ist mir nicht klar, wie der Bezug von *tausend* zu *Zuschauern* hergestellt wird und warum *mit Zuschauern an die tausend* nicht möglich ist bzw. eine andere Bedeutung hätte.

Comment: Das wäre doch dann im Grunde eine Bestätigung der These 1, also Auflösung als "an (die Tausend) Besucher", oder?

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, wie ich es noch eindeutiger formulieren kann: *an die* ist eine Einheit, die das Zahlwort modifiziert. Es ist parallel zu *etwa* (oder *annähernd, fast*). Also für den zweiten Beispielsatz: *Es wird mit etwa tausend Besuchern gerechnet*. Mit Reanalyse ist gemeint: in *reicht an die tausend* verbindet sich *an* mit *die tausend*; aber in *an die tausend Besucher* bilden *an* und *die* eine untrennbare Einheit, die *tausend* modifiziert.

Comment: Man denke bei Reanalyse auch an Präpositionen wie *aufgrund, infolge, anhand*.

Answer (score 0):

Eine möglicherweise in diesem Zusammenhang interessante Frage ist, was "an die 100" (usw.) eigentlich bedeutet. Bedeutet es "ungefähr 100" (also mehr oder weniger oder genau 100) oder nur "eine ungefähre Anzahl, die nicht mehr als 100 sein darf". Mein (unmaßgebliches) Sprachgefühl sagt mir, dass nur Letzteres zutrifft, aber ich habe bisher keine autoritative oder plausible Bestätigung dafür, die meisten (wie meist nur begrenzt hilfreichen) DUDEN-Ausgaben behaupten einfach, "an die 100" sei synonym mit "etwa 100". Stimmt das?

Falls "an die 100" nun "eine ungefähre Anzahl, die nicht mehr als 100 sein darf" bezeichnet, spräche dies deutlich für die Herkunft des Idioms aus einer Form der Präposition "an" ("an ... heran"), also "an die" wäre zu erklären als "an die (Zahl x) heranreichend, aber sie nicht übersteigend". Was das "die" betrifft, könnte es verschiedene Erklärungen geben.